# Send variable and object by query service in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to send variable & object to controller by service in angularjs.
This is my service

```
.service('userService', ['$resource', 'config', function ($resource, config) {
return $resource(config.appRoot + 'api/user/teamname/:progressNo',
    { progressNo: '@ProgressNo' },
    {
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
        }
    }
);
```

}])

and this is call service:

```
        userService.query(condition, { progressNo: $scope.progressNo }, function (data) {});
```

Controller is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("teamname/{progressNo}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> QueryTeamName(int progressNo,UserSearchCondition condition)
    {
        return Json(await this.manager.SelectTeamName(progressNo, condition), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I don't understand why it not call to controller. If i send one object or one param then Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your Action To HttpPost, and similarly change the method in your query too as POST.

Comment: Great...Alternatively you can try passing your condition object json in the querystring the same way you are sending your progressNo.

Comment: I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: Sorry, i'm newbie..i checked it